# Extract a div from response.data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am trying to extract a div from my ajax response in Angular. I do not want to display all the page. I have made things like this but noting worked.

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/angularJS/eg1.html'
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.page = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data)
            $scope.result = $scope.page.document.getElementById('ajax');
        });
```

My view is like this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" ng-bind-html="result">
</div>
```

And the div that i want to display:

```
<div id="ajax">
    <h2>Guess the Number !</h2>
    <p class="well lead">Guess the computer generated random number between 1 and 1000.</p>
    <label>Your Guess: </label><input type="number" ng-model="guess"/>
    <button ng-click="verifyGuess()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Verify</button>
    <button ng-click="initializeGame()" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Restart</button>
    <p>
</div>
```

I am new to angular so be patient:)

Comment: what does `response.data` look like ?

Comment: it is just a html page with two div. Does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can use `jqLite` to get element by `id`.

Like this

```
var elem = angular.element('<div id='dt'> <span id='ajax'>312312</span></div>');
console.log(elem[0].querySelector('#ajax'));
```

Live example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/avf0csnd/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "<div id='dt'> <span id='ajax'>312312</span></div>";
    var elem = angular.element($scope.name);
    console.log(elem[0].querySelector('#ajax'));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form name="testForm">
      <input name="myName" ng-model="name">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Helped a lot! Thank you.